# Cookies and Jwt and when to use them

Tags: java, cookies, jwt

I am new to jwt and after going through some articles I came to an understanding that we can store our jwt in a cookie and the session can still be stateless.Is that right ?, Also as regard to csrf attacks because when using cookies we can be prone to csrf attacks we have anti-forgery to solve the issue of csrf.
Now my main question-  Im not sure if this is correct but ,are there some particular disadvantages to using cookies to store jwt when you are implementing  CrossOrigin for your controllers , that is a scene where my server app is located in a different place and we are calling the api from it in  our client app which is located say in another city ? Isnt that why many webservice providers refrain from using cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can store JWT (that is actually a JWS) in a cookie and still have your session stateless.
2. Yes, there can be a significant rate of danger in using cookies for jwt as regards of CSRF, but it can be mitigated to a minimum by the server controlling the Referrer and Origin header and also by limitation of the Http Cookie lifetime.

I hope it helps.

Comment: can we use @CrossOrigin on our controllers so the can be accessed from a different domain when we are using cookies

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Java controllers, but CORS requests are a completely another dimension of security, so I believe you should just be careful how the cookies are set (to which domain) and mind the CORS headers of the authenticated response.